# Creating mathXxxx type macros for Unicode private use area

Tags: math-mode, macros, xetex, luatex, unicode-math

I have a custom font with a dozen or so scripts 0-9,A-Z,a-z in the private use area. I need to create macros like symcal() and mathcal() for those scripts. I have something that works -- but it is clearly wrong. Since I am trying to get this in shape to put up on ctan, I don't want a kludge that might not work for someone else. Here is my current attempt

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[NFSSFamily=mainfont]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[NFSSFamily=mathfont]

\DeclareSymbolFont{MathFont}{TU}{mathfont}{m}{n}

\usepackage{logix} % Load logix font for additional symbols.

\newcommand \setMathScript {
   \Umathcode "31 = 7 \symLogix "F431
   \Umathcode "41 = 7 \symLogix "F5C1
   \Umathcode "42 = 7 \symLogix "F5C2
   \Umathcode "43 = 7 \symLogix "F5C3 }

\newcommand \clrScript {
   \Umathcode "31 = 7 \symMathFont "31
   \Umathcode "41 = 7 \symMathFont "1D434
   \Umathcode "42 = 7 \symMathFont "1D435
   \Umathcode "43 = 7 \symMathFont "1D436 }

\newcommand \mathCal[1]   {\setMathScript #1 \clrScript}

\begin{document}

   $ A 1 B C \mathCal{ A 1 B C } A 1 B C $ 

   \end{document}
```

and here is the result.

[image]

The first four symbols are the default in math mode. The second four are the result of applying my \mathCal{} macro. The last four are the result of attempting to reset back to the default math mode.

While this works, there are two problems. First, I had to use NFSSFamily=mathfont and \DeclareSymbolFont. Second, I had to hard code the locations of the symbols for the default math font. I cannot assume that a user of the package has done the first or that the second is correct.

Additionally, each of these scripts have a base, in this case F400 for the digits and F580 for the letters. I would prefer to be able to pass in the base(s) and then write something like \add{\base}{"41}. That would substantially reduce the number of lines needed in the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Carlisle the example is now working with both addition and resetting the environment. Here is the working solution.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\usepackage{logix} % Load logix font for additional symbols.

\newcommand \calNumbrBase {"F400}
\newcommand \calAlphaBase {"F580}

\newcommand \setScript {
  \Umathcode "31 = 7 \symLogix \numexpr \calNumbrBase + "31\relax
  \Umathcode "41 = 7 \symLogix \numexpr \calAlphaBase + "41\relax
  \Umathcode "42 = 7 \symLogix \numexpr \calAlphaBase + "42\relax
  \Umathcode "43 = 7 \symLogix \numexpr \calAlphaBase + "43\relax }

\newcommand \mathCal[1]   {{\setScript #1}}

\begin{document}

   $ A 1 B C \mathCal{ A 1 B C } A 1 B C $ 

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to reset the mathcodes to a fixed set, you can use grouping, this typesets as  aba for example

```
$ a {\mathcode`a=\mathcode`b a} a$

\bye
```

Also you can use arithmetic in your settings, for example

```
  \Umathcode "41 = 7 \symMathFont "1D434
```

can be written as

```
\count@="41
\Umathcode \count@ = 7 \symMathFont \numexpr "1D3F3 + \count@\relax
```

which makes it more amenable to being in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The \numexpr will be very useful. As far as the first part with mathcode, I do not see anywhere that I can specify the font family, which is essential since the custom font is NOT the default font. I was thinking some sort of grouping as in an environment would probably do the trick, so that is probably going in the right direction.

Comment: @MichaelLeeFinney the mathcode encodes the font family, you don't need to do it at the point of the switch (I used `\mathcode` but you want `\Umathcode` here of course)

Comment: I do not see a way to set the math code for a symbol in a different font because there is no font family on the left of the equals. So I tried\Umathcode "31 = \Umathcode {\Umathchar 7 \symLogix "F431} but while LuaLaTeX accepted it at the point of definition, it did not like where it was used. Without being able to set the mathcode in the custom font, I still don't see how I can use this.

Comment: The Umathcode _encodes_ the font. ` \Umathcode "41 = 7 \symMathFont "1D434` specifies that character hex 41 comes from font family \symMathFont  so you do not need anything else. @MichaelLeeFinney

Comment: Thank you. I got that to work! It needed an extra set of braces to get the grouping. I will update my answer showing the solution that worked.

Comment: post an answer, don't put answers in the question, thanks @MichaelLeeFinney

Comment: Did that, and checked your answer. One related followup question, would I use \mathord for symXxxx and \mathalpha for mathXxxx? unicode-math treats them slightly differently, and that is the only thing that I could see that makes sense.